# How can i apply Policy sets to SCA individual web service methods in websphere

Tags: websphere, sca, apache-tuscany

I have deployed a Tuscany SCA component (developed in IBM Rational Application Developer) to WebSphere 8.5. It has a Web Service binding, with 5 methods. I want to apply different Policy Sets to each method. However, in the Admin Console, under Service Providers, I can only see the Service, and the Endpoint - ie No Operations are listed.

I can do this just fine at the Operation level with regular JAX-WS service components.

This is day 2 of trying to solve this. I've tried all of the SCA Annotations in the Java implementation code, but no joy.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I'm following your question entirely, but here what I think is the answer.
In SCA, you don't define the policies at the Service Providers level, instead you can specify them in the SCA Composite file, at the implementation, services and/or references levels.

WAS Knowledge Center has comprehensive documentation about how to accomplish the task of adding and configuring Policies in SCA applications. Open this link and scroll down to the configure Security for SCA applications.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/welc6tech_sca_links.html?lang=en

You can have a better glance in this document, which is the SCA Policies spec

http://docs.oasis-open.org/opencsa/sca-policy/sca-policy-1.1.pdf

Comment: Hi Victor, we ave been deploying the SCA composites, which have Web Service bindings exposed. In WAS, these show up as SCA-SERVICES under the Service Providers tab. Here, we were attaching Policies. I have never seen the document you linked me to - it looks great. We are still on 8.5. I will study it and see if it helps. Many thanks.

Comment: OK, I think I have my answer, and sadly, it's as I suspected. From the text: "SCA does not support operation level attachments."